# Convert a hex string to a hex int

Tags: ruby, literals

I have to convert a hexadecimal string to a hexadecimal integer, like this:

```
color = "0xFF00FF" #can be any color else, defined by functions
colorto = 0xFF00FF #copy of color, but from string to integer without changes
```

I can have RGB format too.

I'm obliged to do this because this function goes after :

```
def i2s int, len
  i = 1
  out = "".force_encoding('binary')
  max = 127**(len-1)

  while i <= len
    num = int/max
    int -= num*max
    out << (num + 1)
    max /= 127
    i += 1
  end

  out
end
```

I saw [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm) that hexadecimal integers exist. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Why would you expect `color.to_i` to be anything other than `0`? You've read the api docs (http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i) that show that the base defaults to '10', so your string with a zero then 'x' would be seen as decimal zero. You need to tell the `to_i` method that your string is a hex string -- and the API shows that.

Comment: Friendly reminder that there's no such a thing as a hex int. The hexadecimal string "0xF", the decimal string "15", the octal string "017", and the binary string "0b1111" are the same integer. It's no different than how 'hello', 'Привет', and '你好' mean the same thing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'd need supply integer base argument to `String#to_i` method:

```
irb> color = "0xFF00FF"
irb> color.to_i(16)
=> 16711935
irb> color.to_i(16).to_s(16)
=> "ff00ff"
irb> '%#X' % color.to_i(16)
=> "0XFF00FF"
```

Comment: @FrereDePute Wut ?! `color.to_i(16) == 0xff00ff    # true`

Answer (score 16):

First off, an integer is never hexadecimal. Every integer has a hexadecimal *representation*, but that is a string.

To convert a string containing a hexadecimal representation of an integer with the `0x` prefix to an integer in Ruby, call the function `Integer` on it.

```
Integer("0x0000FF") # => 255
```

Comment: Or alternatively, `Integer("0000FF", 16)`

Comment: Upvoting this because this gives me what I needed to solve my particular problem - a way to parse strings that properly handles the standard representations for bases - so `Integer("0x10")`, `Integer("010")`, `Integer("10")`, and even `Integer("0b10")` all give different answers (16, 8, 10, and 2, respectively).  Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

`2.1.0 :402 > "d83d".hex
 => 55357`